# Why can't I access a default argument in its initializer in gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

This compiles in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f882f16b94e18f60) but not in [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f36ac097578d8f05):

```c++
void f(int x = decltype(x){});
```

The error in gcc says that `x` was not declared in this scope but according to 3.3.2/1 the variable `x` should be in scope:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below. [Example:
>
> ```c++
> int x = 12;
> { int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second `x` is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. — end example ]

So is clang correct? Should `x` be accessible in its own initializer?

PS: `int x = x` as a parameter fails in both compilers but I don't know why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GCC is correct; that's not valid.

> C++11 8.3.6/9 [dcl.fct.default] parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not evaluated.

Comment: So does that mean there's a bug in Clang? Should it be reported?

Comment: @templateboy The standard is too imprecise and should allow cases where a parameter occurs in an unevaluated operand of a default argument.

Comment: @templateboy: It's arguable whether Clang or the standard should be fixed. There's no good reason to prohibit it unless it's evaluated.